# Why do these lace threads reflect light in this way?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

I was watching a video about the making of leavers lace and came across this. I'm wondering why the threads reflect the light as seen in the picture. How does that work?

[image]

I took a screenshot from this video at the 2:10 minute mark. If you need more information:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5uX143hx38&ab_channel=BusinessInsider

Comment: Diffraction. An early diffraction grating was made simply by using two finely threaded screws and hairs would to make the grating.

Comment: Heh heh. Dueling YouTube vids.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6dZjuw1KUo